# How to move png across the line

Tags: html, css

I have these two css commands.

```
code h1 {
background: #000000;
border-radius: 6px;
color: #fff;
display: block;
font: 40px/60px "Sans", Inconsolata, "Lucida Console", Terminal, "Courier New", Courier;
padding: 40px 40px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 0% 40px 0%;
.header img {
float: right;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #000000;
```

One for putting Name of the website in the middle surrounding it with black bar. Logo of the website is currently in the right corner on the same line as the text but how can I move it from the very right a little bit to the left. As I understand float: right doest work together with margin-right but by using margin, only logo is not on the same line as text,

Comment: Flexbox is your friend! Flexbox gives you way more control over elements and is highly responsive. A helpfull guide is: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex boxes:

```
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**UPD.**

The Flexible Box Layout Module, makes it easier to design flexible responsive layout structure without using float or positioning.

- To define flex box modal, we are using **display: flex** property in css.
- The **justify-content** property is used to align the flex items. Possible options are:

  - **flex-start** (default): items are packed toward the start.
  - **flex-end**: items are packed toward the end.
  - **start**: items are packed toward the start.
  - **end**: items are packed toward the end.
  - **left**: items are packed toward left edge of the container.
  - **right**: items are packed toward right edge of the container.
  - **center**: items are centered along the line
  - **space-between**: items are evenly distributed in the line; first item is on the start line, last item on the end line
  - **space-around**: items are evenly distributed in the line with equal space around them. Note that visually the spaces aren't equal, since all the items have equal space on both sides. The first item will have one unit of space against the container edge, but two units of space between the next item because that next item has its own spacing that applies.
  - **space-evenly**: items are distributed so that the spacing between any two items (and the space to the edges) is equal.
- The **align-items** property is used to align the flex items vertically:

  - **stretch** (default): stretch to fill the container (still respect min-width/max-width)
  - **flex-start / start / self-start**: items are placed at the start of the cross axis.
  - **flex-end / end / self-end**: items are placed at the end of the cross axis.
  - **center**: items are centered in the cross-axis
  - **baseline**: items are aligned such as their baselines align

Useful information: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp#align-items

This is **must to know** for every web developers.

Comment: No, What happens if CSS-tricks website goes down or their information / url / intent changes. It is better to answer with a clear *guide* as well as some example code. Code only answers are not generally helpful . THanks.